# Parsing a string to another string in PHP

Tags: php, string-parsing

I have a string that looks like `"/Images/Folder/1.jpeg"` or `"/Images/Folder/55.jpeg"`

How do I parse this string so I can get the digit "1" or "55" for example into a string of its own?

The `/Images/Folder/` and the `".jpeg"` will be constant so I could use them as delimiters.

Comment: Regex is nice but really not needed for something so simple (in reply to someones deleted comment). http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @Jesse yes, sorry my bad. I totally forgot about `explode`.

Comment: The [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function exists specifically for breaking down a filepath like this: `$digits = pathinfo("/Images/Folder/1.jpeg", PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Comment: $i=`intval( basename( $imgpath ) );` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$s = "/Images/Folder/1.jpeg";
$temp = explode('/', $s);
$temp2 = explode('.', $temp[count($temp) - 1]);
echo $temp2[0];
```

Result:

```
1
```